# Spring batch chicken and egg: transient JPA reference

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have a Spring-Batch process which Reads from Bar to create a new Foo:

```
/* My Foo Step */
class FooStepConfig {
    ItemReader<Bar> reader; // Reads records from Bar
    ItemProcessor<Bar, Foo> processor; // Determines whether to create a new Foo or update an existing Foo
    ItemReader<Foo> writer; // Created/Updated Foos are persisted
    // ...
}
```

Additionally, when creating or updating a `Foo`, I need to also save a `FooNotification` that references the Foo:

```
// During processor step, this is saved
@Entity
public FooNotification {
    @Id Long id;
    @ManyToOne Foo foo; // @Entity class Foo { ... };
    @Enumerated NotificationType nt; // new, updated, removed, etc... 
                                     // (removal is a soft delete with "Foo.isActive" column) 
}
```

`ItemProcessor`:

```
class MyItemProcessor extends ItemProcessor<Foo, Bar> {
    ...
    public Foo process(Bar bar) { 
        Foo foo = fromBar(bar); // some supporting method defined elsewhere.
        ...
        // does not work as foo is still transient at this point and id is null as it is generated on persist from a Database Sequence.
        fooNotificationRepository.save(new FooNotification(foo,...));
        ...
        return Foo;
    }
}
```

As described in the comments above, when the batch process runs through, I receive the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException:↩ 
  ↪object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient↩ 
  ↪instance before flushing : com.example.FooNotification.foo -> com.example.Foo
```

---

Both `Foo` creation/mutation and `FooNotification` creation should be atomic. I don't want either to exist without the other, so spliting the two into seperate steps isn't ideal. Also the `FooNotification` can contain information about what fields changes and previous values, so calculating that at the time of the update is much more efficient.

**I know I can solve this** by creating an `ItemProcessor<Bar, FooNotification>` and `ItemWriter<FooNotification>` as the saves would cascade with appropriate configuration and the `Foo` should always exist for each type. conceptually though, this isn't the purpose of the step and feels awkward. `FooNotification`s are a side product of the main `Foo` creation and not the main batch step's objective.

- Is there another more sensible way I can ensure the creation of the `Foo` before the `FooNotification`?
- Do I need to 'pre-create' the `Foo` unfinished in order for the reference to be a valid orm managed entity?

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:

1. A [listener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemWriteListener.html)
2. Move notification creation to writing phase: use a single writer or a composite one; the first for for `Foo` and latest for `FooNotification`

Comment: A listener is something that I would like to avoid as compiling the change manifest is much easier as the changes are being applied. I have opted for a composite change writer, but not exactly as described in step 2. I'll document the full solution as soon as I'm done with the implementation. You have my up-vote though :)